# Equality for Dimensions of Vector Spaces of Meromorphic Functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I am reading a proof in algebraic geometry where the following equality is used:

$\text{dim} \: L(C,K_C) = \text{dim} \: L(C,K_C + P),$

where $L(C,D)$ is the vector space of meromorphic functions with specified poles on a compact Riemann surface or a non-singular projective algebraic curve, $D$ is a divisor, $K_C$ is a canonical divisor of $C$ and $P$ is a point which belongs to $C$.

In more usual notation, the identity would be

$l(K) = l(K+P).$

Is there some simple way to see that this equality is true (perhaps some complex analytic argument), it seems intuitively obvious to me.

Comment: Since $L(C,K_C) \subset L(C,K_C+P)$, one has to verify that $\dim L(C,K_C+P) = g(C)$, since $\dim L(C,K_C) = g(C)$. This follows from Riemann-Roch, since $\dim L(C,-P) = 0$.

Comment: I think I actually saw the identity being used in a proof for Riemann-Roch, so unfortunately I can't prove it using that theorem!  Is there some other way to verify it?

Comment: Could you tell us what one is allowed to use?

Comment: Anything but the Riemann-Roch formula (if that's possible).

Comment: Do you know about sheaves? So that $L(C,K_C)$ is the space of global sections of $\mathcal O_C(K_C)$? Then one could consider the long exact cohomology sequence associated to $0 \to \mathcal O_C(K_C) \to \mathcal O_C(K_C+P) \to Q \to 0$, where $Q$ is the quotient and is a skyscraper-sheaf supported on $P$.

Comment: Yes I have some familiarity with sheaves and cohomology.  Ok, that sounds like a good idea, it's just I didn't want to assume the result to be true without checking.